# In Azure DevOps, after configuring self-hosted, maven build job is taking too long to complete the build job

Tags: maven, azure-devops, proxy

In Azure DevOps, after configuring self-hosted, maven build job is taking too long to complete the build job,.
I have added below proxy in runsvc.sh:

```
export DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=1
export VSTS_HTTP_PROXY=http://<my proxy here>
```

I see below warning in Maven build:

> ##[warning]Failed to upload file TestResults_484.zip to Blob Transfer exception with errorcode Unknown, exception message Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferException: The transfer failed.  ---> Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException: Network is unreachable